# SQL derived table. Easy SQL

Tags: sql, database

Hi i get the error 'Every derived table must have its own alias' what can i do about it??

My question is : 
Show team ID and names from teams from Germany who have never played in UEFA Champions league

```
UEFA Champions league = 1
Cid= Competions ID
Tid = Team ID


SELECT teams.TID, teams.name from(
SELECT Tid1 FROM(
(SELECT tid1,cid FROM matches
     WHERE tid1 IN (SELECT tid FROM teams WHERE country='Germany')
                   UNION
 SELECT tid2,cid FROM matches
    WHERE tid2 IN (SELECT tid FROM teams WHERE country='Germany'))
 )WHERE cid <> (SELECT cid FROM competitions WHERE cid='1'))
 INNER JOIN matches ON tid1=team.tid;
```

I have tried looking at others derived soulutions but i cant get to work with mine...

Comment: You can literally copy/paste the error into Google and get the answer...

Comment: a subquery needs a name: `(select x from y) as some_alias_name` - except when in an `IN()` clause.

Comment: ANSI SQL has no such requirement. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You will get Problems here: `cid <> (SELECT cid FROM competitions WHERE cid='1'))` because the query can return more than one value

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its asking for you to give alias to the tables you have created within the query. Try this.

```
EFA Champions league = 1
Cid= Competions ID
Tid = Team ID

SELECT teams.TID, teams.name from(
SELECT Tid1 FROM(
(SELECT tid1,cid FROM matches
     WHERE tid1 IN (SELECT tid FROM teams WHERE country='Germany')
                   UNION
 SELECT tid2,cid FROM matches
    WHERE tid2 IN (SELECT tid FROM teams WHERE country='Germany'))ALIAS1
 )WHERE cid <> (SELECT cid FROM competitions WHERE cid='1')) ALIAS2
 INNER JOIN matches ON tid1=team.tid;
```